# Ubuntu Server gets kicked off LAN periodically / when another device joins LAN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I'm running into an issue with my newly created Ubuntu server.  Full Disclosure: I'm pretty new to both networking and Ubuntu, so I may have missed any basic setup step that would address this problem.

My Ubuntu server is wired to my Archer C7 router. I set DHCP up so that the server will retain the same IP address every time I turn it on (192.168.0.108). After a random length of time, the server will disconnect, and remain offline until I restart the server.

Other times, when I connect my tablet to the Wifi, it will force the Ubuntu server to disconnect, and the Ubuntu server will not reconnect until I remove my tablet from the Wifi, and delete it from the ARP cache.

The tablet will take the IP address reserved for the Ubuntu server on occasion. I double checked and I set the correct MAC address for the server in the DHCP reservation list, and I did not set any DHCP reservation for the MAC address of the tablet.

Does anyone know any major flaw that I might have committed, or any setting I should check, either on the Ubuntu server or the router?

Comment: have you confirmed that they have different MACs? It's been years, but in the old days I came across duplicate MACs far more often than expected (eg never). is MAC changer installed on either device? Are you absolutely sure that your wifi infrastructure is not assigning the IP rahter than your core router's DHCP service? have you considered sniffing with wireshark to watch the DHCP negotiation?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there's some arp conflicting going on from the tablet or the router is giving your tablet a higher priority in the dhcp tables. Try setting an IP reservation for the tablet on the router and seeing if that helps.

Considering this is a modern TP-link router, check your QoS setting on the router as some router manufacturers (nearly all modern COTS routers in the past three years found in big box stores) use an non or incomplete RFC compliant stack. So their QoS implementation can wreck havoc on a linux based home network. Don't forget to disable WPS as well, same reasoning as the QoS plus it can be hacked with a free app in google play or just by any other wps cracker.